# ¿Por que no se me imprime en consola el System.out.println que hay en el while?

Tags: java, while

```
package Ejercicio15;

public class AcumuladorInteractivo {
private double nota;

//GET AND SET

public double getNota() {
    return nota;
}
public void setNota(double nota) {
    this.nota = nota;
}

//METODOS

public double media(double nota) {
    double nuevaNota = 0;
    double notaTotal = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
        notaTotal = notaTotal + nota; 
        nuevaNota++;
    }while(nota <= 0);
    return notaTotal/nuevaNota;
}
}
```

Clase con metodo main

```
package Ejercicio15;
import java.util.*;
public class AcumuladorInteractivoApp {
   public static void main(String[]args) {
      AcumuladorInteractivo a = new AcumuladorInteractivo();
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      a.media(sc.nextDouble());
      sc.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Te marca un error o qué es  lo que ocurre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La sentencia siguiente en tu bucle:

```
System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
```

... ocurre ***después*** de la ejecución de la siguiente sentencia en tu `main`:

```
sc.nextDouble()
```

O sea que la consola está esperando que entres un número ***antes*** de que tu imprimas el mensaje pidiéndolo.

Puedes comprobar esto al entrar un número + ENTER, y verás como el mensaje aparece. Obviamente, tienes un problema de lógica en tu programa (en realidad tienes mas de un problema en tu programa). Te tocará reordenar tus sentencias adecuadamente.